# What happens if the central portion of a Handy haversack is pierced?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

The *handy haversack* has

> two side pouches, each of which appears large enough to hold about a quart of material. In fact, each is like a bag of holding [...]

I can imagine that if either of the pouch is pierced it is

> ruined and contents are lost forever

as with a *bag of holding*.

The large central portion, no matter how much it is filled, *always weights 5 pounds.*

**What happens if this central part is pierced?** In the book it is not explicit that it works like a *bag of holding*, still it looks like it works similarly.

Comment: I am not sure what the part about the 5 pounds adds to the question? Probably you can remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The central part is the same except for capacity

> In fact, each is like a bag of holding and [...]. The large central portion of the pack can contain up to 8 cubic feet or 80 pounds of material.

The fact that the central portion works the same but is larger is implied by the fact that this part too is unnaturally large and the sentence is structures like the preceding sentence which makes the connection to the *Bag of Holding*. So you should read it like

> The central portion also works like a Bag of Holding but at four times the capacity.